# Missing route after cache rebuild in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

have a module called phys_custom which defines a route, phys_custom.homepage (/homepage), which works fine, until I clear the cache, at which point it is no longer available.

Take a look at the following output. For now I need to always uninstall and reinstall my module every time I clear my cache. How would I go about debugging this?

```
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys cr
[success] Cache rebuild complete.
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys pmu phys_custom
[success] Successfully uninstalled: phys_custom
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys pm:enable phys_custom
[success] Successfully enabled: phys_custom
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys ev 'print_r(drupal_get_path("module", "phys_custom") . PHP_EOL)'
sites/phys/modules/phys_custom
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys ev 'print_r(\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("phys_custom.homepage")->toString() . PHP_EOL)'
/homepage
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys cr
[success] Cache rebuild complete.
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys ev 'print_r(drupal_get_path("module", "phys_custom") . PHP_EOL)'
sites/phys/modules/phys_custom
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys ev 'print_r(\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute("phys_custom.homepage")->toString() . PHP_EOL)'

In RouteProvider.php line 201:

 Route "phys_custom.homepage" does not exist.
```

I am using drush 9.6.2 and Drupal 8.6.15

I also opened an [issue on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3051123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a core bug currently being worked on, [Extensions in Multisite Directories Not Registered When Rebuilding Cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2985199) . The patch there fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This `-l phys` part in your command may be the cause of the issue.

Drush `-l` option purpose is to target a particular site in a multisite installations, it expects a URI  :

```
-l <uri> , --uri=<uri> URI of the Drupal site to use. 
 The value of --uri should always be the same as when
 the site is being accessed from a web browser (e.g. http://example.com)
```

That said, you shouldn't have to specify it as soon as the alias *@stewardd8.test* is well defined, by which I mean at least these 2 options appear in the corresponding site alias definition :

```
test:
  root: /path/to/stewardd8
  uri: http://example.com
```

With these options set correctly, you can run `drush status` and check the output :

```
$ drush @stewardd8.test status
Drupal version                  :  8.6.14
Site URI                        :  http://example.com    # <- as expected
```

But, if you override the site URI with `-l phys` things may not work as expected :

```
$ drush @stewardd8.test -l phys status
Drupal version                  :  8.6.14
Site URI                        :  phys                  # <- invalid
```

So I suggest you start fixing this before digging further. Also you can add the `-v, --verbose` option to make drush more wordy, e.g. `drush -v @stewardd8.test cr`.

Then if it doesn't fix the missing route issue, I would scrutinize Drupal/PHP/SQL logs (in that order) especially when running the cache rebuild command.

Comment: Thanks, however although -l normally accepts a URL, it also accept a string if it is defined in ./sites/sites.php as such `$sites['example.com'] = 'phys';`, which allows us to define several sites using the same multisite directory (in this case "phys"), so it turned out that was not the problem, see my answer above, it is a core bug which was causing this.

Comment: @alberto56 I did not know about this drush -l feature with multisite, thanks for the clarification !

Comment: (though I noticed `drush status` outputs 'phys' as site URI even after registering 'phys' in ./sites/sites.php, it is misleading but drush bootstraps the site correctly - drush 8.x)